# Is it possible to share memory between docker containers?

Tags: docker, linux-containers

I work on an application with different processes and I'm asked to contain those processes for achieving more isolation.

The problem is that the processes share memory with a single "hypervisor" process in order to exchange data (they use classic shared buffers). This solution was implemented for performance requirement and because it is running in user-space, so there aren't content switching between user-space and kernel-space.

If I'm not wrong is not possible to run more than one docker container inside a single IPC namespace, but I don't know if it is possible that a single docker container belongs to different IPC namespaces, this could solve my problem.

Other solutions are welcome, just keep in mind that performance is a requirement, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`--ipc=host` and `--ipc=container:id`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc) options have since been added to the Docker [`create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) and [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) commands to share IPC resources.

> ```
> --ipc=""  : Set the IPC mode for the container,
>              'container:<name|id>': reuses another container's IPC namespace
>              'host': use the host's IPC namespace inside the container
> ```

IPC with the host

```
docker run --ipc=host <image>
```

IPC with another container

```
docker run --ipc=container:<id> <image>
```

IPC with another container may need the `shareable` option set on the initial container (if dockerd defaults IPC to `private`)

```
docker run --ipc=shareable <image>
```

Answer (score 17):

Technically, you can share the same IPC namespace between containers, but Docker doesn't support that (yet).

If you can use `mmap()` instead of IPC, then you could share a volume between both containers, and map a file on that volume; it will be the same file, and therefore be shared correctly.

If you really need to share the IPC namespace (because you can't change the existing code), then it's time to write some Go code and contribute it to Docker :-)

The easiest path would probably be to add a flag to the libcontainer binding, so that you can start a container reusing the IPC namespace of the host (or of another container). Check the implementation of the `--net` flag, since it achieves exactly that, but for the network namespace.

Comment: (I don't know if this is a real concern, but using tmpfs for the shared volume would reduce the chance that anything would be unnecessarily flushed to disk.)

Comment: It is great info. But how can I validate if under covers it is doing that. I mean not flusing to disk. Any idea?

Comment: As far as I understand mmap() this would not be possible in this situation. 
To use mmap() for IPC you have to set the MAP_SHARED flag. But this flag only count for processes **forked** out of the main process.

Comment: MAP_SHARED works across unrelated processes as long as you map a file 

Answer (score 9):

As suggested by [@jpetazzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580281/jpetazzo) I looked ad the source of Docker and also with the help of devs guys on [#docker-dev](https://botbot.me/freenode/docker-dev/) I successfully [recompiled Docker](https://docs.docker.com/contributing/devenvironment/) in order to drop the IPC namespace.

To achieve this, it is necessary to comment the line `"NEWIPC": true,` in the file `default_template.go` located in the folder `docker/daemon/execdriver/native/template` of the Docker source code.

The old code now works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here how it is work:

start container with shareable  ipc

```
docker run -it --rm --ipc="shareable" --name cont1 ubuntu
```

then start next container and share with its ipc

```
docker run -it --rm --name cont2 --ipc container:cont1 ubuntu
```