# communication between containers in docker

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers

Is there any to way to communicate among docker containers other than via sockets/network? I have read docker documentation which says we can link docker containers using --link option but it doesn't speicify how to transfer data/msg from one container to another. I have already created a container named checkram. 
Now I want to link a new container with this container and I run
`docker run -i -t --privileged --link=checkram:linkcheck --name linkcont topimg` command.
Then i checked env variable `LINKCHECK_PORT` in linkcont container which contains **tcp://172.17.0.14:22**. 
I don't know what to do with this ip and port and how to communicate with checkram container from linkcont container. can anyone help me out of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not a question about programming and is much better suited for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: What kind of "communication" do you want?

Comment: data should be exchanged among containers but not through sockets..whether it can be IPC or some other means..is it feasible?

Comment: @user3550166 No, not really. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889187/is-it-possible-to-share-memory-between-docker-containers

Comment: You could use volumes to mount the same volume in both containers and then write from one and read from the next. I am not sure of how efficient this model is but it allows you to communicate without using sockets.

Comment: @usman-but is that one way communication?

Comment: No, it is not. You can also mmap files from volumes, use BSD sockets or other stuff. It really depends on what kind of communication you want. Using TCP with netcat is reasonably easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools you can use to achieve running multiple docker containers and interact with them.  docker has a tool:  [docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) where you can build and interact multiple containers.

Another tool that works as well:  [decking](https://github.com/makeusabrew/decking-example)    you can also use FIG, but i found decking was very straight forward and easy to configure.  At that time when i was using decking, docker compose was not released yet.  docker compose is a newer tool, yet it is developed by docker.

Comment: if you chose to use decking, then you will use decking to pass the environment variables to docker containers as parameters