# Can a docker process access programms on the host with ipc

Tags: docker, ipc, ibm-mq

I´m working on a clustered tomcat system that uses MQSeries.
Today MQSeries is accessed in bindings mode, i.e. via IPC and tomcat and mqeries run on the same host without any virtualization/docker support.

I´d like to transform that to a solution, where mqseries runs on the host (or possible in a docker container) the the tomcat instances run in docker containers.

It´s possible to access mqseries in client mode (via a tcp connection) and this seems to be the right solution.

Would it still be possible to access mqseries from the docker container via ipc, i.e. create exceptions for the ipc namespace separation? Is anything like that planned for docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **docker 1.5** this is possible with the flag `--ipc=host` like in

```
docker run --ipc=host ubuntu bash
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162010/448734) suggests how IPC can be enabled with a source-code modification to Docker.  As far as I (and the other answers there) know, there is no built-in feature.

Specificically, he says he commented out [this line](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/execdriver/native/template/default_template.go#L31) which makes Docker create a separate IPC namespace.

Rebuilding Docker is a bit tedious because it brings in dozens of other things during the build, but if you follow the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/contributing/devenvironment/) it's straightforward.